# QVector spends different times when adding an element

Tags: c++, qt, vector

I have a very simple code, I noticed that if I add values ​​to `QVector` constants, then I spend a lot of time than if I add sequential knowledge

**code example:**

```
QVector<int> intVector;

QTime myTimer;
myTimer.start();
for (int i = 0; i < 8500000; ++i) {
    intVector.push_back(i);
}
qDebug()<< myTimer.elapsed(); // output: ~297 ms
```

but if i add a constant value i get this

**code example:**

```
QVector<int> intVector;
    
QTime myTimer;
myTimer.start();
for (int i = 0; i < 8500000; ++i) {
    intVector.push_back(1); 
}
qDebug()<< myTimer.elapsed(); // output: ~344 ms
```

tested on `Qt_5_15_0_MSVC2019_32bit`.

What explains this?

Comment: did you turn on optimizations? the difference between 297 and 344 isnt that big. Did you repeat the measurement to get an idea of the uncertainty?

Comment: Yes, the difference is not big, but it is, I repeated it several times, the result is the same

Comment: what command did you use to compile? Is it a debug or release build?

Comment: QT creator Qt_5_15_0 , debug build

Comment: try to see what happens in a release build. Measuring runtime in a debug build is almost meaningless because without optimizations c++ can be arbitrarily slow

Comment: release build : `push_back(i)`  47 ms ,  `push_back(1)`  62 ms ,

Comment: are the two snippets in seperate binaries? Details matter, please post a [mcve]

Comment: this is a fairly simple example, I run them one by one, first I test on `push_back(i)`, and then I change the code and test on `push_back(1)`, and I get this result, and I run each of them several times

Answer (score 1):

Don't use QTimer to do microbenchmarks, use the [google-benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) library instead.

On my system (M1 mac) both loops are equal to within 0,04%:

```
------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark            Time             CPU   Iterations
------------------------------------------------------
BM_constant    1211287 ns      1211286 ns          510
BM_i           1211735 ns      1211229 ns          573
```

Code:

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <QtCore/QVector>

static void BM_constant(benchmark::State& state) {
    for (auto _ : state) {
        QVector<int> intVector;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
            intVector.push_back(1);
        }
    }
}
BENCHMARK(BM_constant);

static void BM_i(benchmark::State& state) {
    for (auto _ : state) {
        QVector<int> intVector;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
            intVector.push_back(i);
        }
    }
}
BENCHMARK(BM_i);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```